# how i can parse link in herf = javascript:void(0) which is hidden using python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

i am try to parse a link which is hidden in `herf = javascript:void(0)` and get link button is disable `class="btn btn-success btn-lg get-link disabled"`.  after some second link is appear `<a href="http://googledrivedirectlink.xyz/download.php?id=QllDSWJsSGV1M3RRd0c3N1o0QmVWdUpoZVdJUjZ4ZE9iWkx6ZHgvZllmNlc=" class="btn btn-success btn-lg get-link">Get Link</a>`. how i can solve this how i can use Selenium for parse href link

i have already tried it with BeautifulSoup but its not working nothing show its say

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn btn-success btn-lg get-link disabled">
  Please wait...        
</a>
```

how i can resolve it

here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url=requests.get('http://linkblend.icu/p8AzvIvi').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(url,'html.parser')
soup.findAll('a')
```

Here is my code output

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn btn-success btn-lg get-link disabled">
  Please wait...    
</a>
```

Comment: So, what are you trying to get exactly? What is your desired output?

Comment: Following link can help you I guess:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python
Basically you need to wait for the Javascript of the page to run completely before reading the link href

Comment: thanks for reply. sir i want  href link which i have described . using parsing in python.

Comment: @KeerthiKumarP thanks for reply. yeah i want  to make some wait requests for javascript for rum completely .  for getting href link.. but how i can get it with code in python  please have you some idea

Comment: Yeah, the link in my comment has many options for that. Particularly this answer seems to be clear: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26440563/6016779 Kindly try them and raise a separate thread if you have any issues in them.

Comment: Here's the thing, if you're literally trying to get `"javascript: void(0)"` that's easy, but that's not a "link." If you're trying to get a link, yea, @"Keerthi Kumar P"'s advice will first need to be taken into account and Python libraries can assist, but I find that both Beautiful Soup and Selenium often fail to find the right tags especially when unicode characters are involved so I often use regex and pass what I find back in. You can try this: `re.findall('href=\"([\S]+)\"(?=\s|$)', url)`. BTW `url` in your code is a string.

Comment: sorry sir its not working :(

Comment: Wait, what? Are you waiting for everything to load as said? I just test this in Python like this `>>> import re` set part of your sample to a variable "url"  `>>> url = '''href="http://googledrivedirectlink.xyz/download.php?id=QllDSWJsSGV1M3RRd0c3N1o0QmVWdUpoZVdJUjZ4ZE9iWkx6ZHgvZllmNlc=" class="btn btn-success btn-lg get-link">Get Link</a>'''` ------------------------------ Ran it against the regex and got this result  `>>> re.findall('href=\"([\S]+)\"(?=\s|$)', url)`  `#RESULT: ['http://googledrivedirectlink.xyz/download.php?id=QllDSWJsSGV1M3RRd0c3N1o0QmVWdUpoZVdJUjZ4ZE9iWkx6ZHgvZllmNlc=']`

Comment: no sir  this is url where i want to get href link from this link `'url= http://linkblend.icu/p8AzvIvi'` . when i open this link its still load for 3 second after 3 second its appear replace of `"javascript: void(0)"`. but its not able to parse

Comment: Sir you just open url which i mention uper comment and check inspect of getlink button.u will understand my problem